# Short expression to convey "but consider the source"

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice, latin

Is there a short phrase (one to three words), Latin or otherwise, that conveys "but consider the source"?

For example, "I heard that pigs fly on television (*your phrase here*)."

I'm thinking perhaps a phrase that begins with the Latin word "caveat".

Comment: _Caveat auditor_ means 'Let the hearer beware'; any Latin verb can be made into an agentive noun by adding -tor to the infinitive stem.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks.  What would the appropriate phrase be for 'Let the reader beware'?

Comment: _Legere_ is the infinitive of 'to read'; its agentive form is _lector_ -- the final /ɡ/ of the athematic infinitive stem _leg-_ devoices to /k/ (spelled C in Latin) by assimilation with the /t/ of -_tor_. So _Caveat Lector_ in the singular, and _Caveant Lectores_ if you want to say 'readers'.

Comment: I would say "Sez who?"

Answer (score 2):

You are probably thinking of *[caveat emptor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caveat+emptor)*, let the buyer beware.

*Merriam-Webster*

This is reported as *new Latin*, dating back to the 16th century.

While it literally refers to purchases, it often is used more generally to mean, *be wary*.

Comment: That's the one that keeps popping in mind, but I was concerned I would be laughed out of here if I mentioned it.  Doesn't that Latin phrase really apply to buying things and not to the more general "consider the source"?

Comment: *Consider the source* is a pretty good phrase.

Comment: In this SE question ( http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/919/what-needs-to-be-exposed-for-the-body-to-produce-vitamin-d ) would it have been appropriate to include "caveat emptor" after the words "television show"?

Comment: Well, advertising based TV is in constant sell mode, whether it is promoting products or points of view. They want you to *buy in* to the offered *wisdom*.

Comment: Very true, but the average reader won't make that connection.  Let's say it wasn't advertising-based TV (I don't recall where or how it was broadcast); would "caveat emptor" be appropriate?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - If you trust your reader's imagination, caveat emptor does not directly say *sort of*, but it does imply just that: Don't buy *that* unskeptically.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the figurative phrase "take it with a grain of salt," if you adjust the original sentence slightly:

> "I heard that pigs fly, but the report was on television, so take it with a grain of salt."

The idiom is defined in Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) as follows:

> **with a grain of salt** Also, **with a pinch of salt**. Skeptically, with reservations. For example, *I always take Sandy's stories about illnesses with a grain of salt—she tends to exaggerate*. This expression is a translation of the Latin *cum grano salis*, which Pliny used in describing Pompey's discovery of an antidote for poison (to be taken with a grain of salt). It was soon adopted by English writers.