# what is its proverb in English

Tags: american-english, british-english, proverbs, proverb-requests

there is a famous proverb in Nepal, i.e. कागले कान समात्यो भन्दैमा  म कागको पछि लग्नु. The meaning of this proverb to believe other blindly.  For example: "The man said someone that the crow grabbed his ear, and he without checking his ear chases the crow."

The moral is we should not believe what other people say immediately. And I want proverb in this.

Is there some PROVERB in English related to this scenario?
Thanks

Comment: Is believing others blindly a good thing or a bad thing? Or is it about the ability of the crow to make the man follow? I understand the actions described, but not the meaning behind the actions. What's the so-called moral of the story?

Comment: Maybe something like this quote from Edgar Allan Poe: *Believe nothing you hear, and only one half that you see.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Its a bad thing.

Comment: @TinfoilHat good one. Is there any other too? :)

Comment: @JasonBassford the moral is we should not believe what other people say immediately. And I want proverb in this

Comment: A common idiom in the US is simply "Don't believe everything you hear."  And, of course, there are many variations.

Comment: @HotLicks A nice variant I've seen as a bumper-sticker is "Don't believe everything you think."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short expression to convey "but consider the source"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245306/short-expression-to-convey-but-consider-the-source) Answers include 'take it with a pinch/grain of salt' and 'caveat emptor'. Also, at [spoken word equivalent for for 'paper does not refuse ink'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535555/spoken-word-equivalent-for-paper-does-not-refuse-ink), 'Believe only half of what you see and nothing you hear'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **Trust, but verify**? From Wikipedia:

> **[Trust, but verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust,_but_verify)** is a rhyming Russian proverb. The phrase became internationally known in English when used by President Ronald Reagan on several occasions in the context of nuclear disarmament discussions with the Soviet Union.

It means don't "take at face value," which is another idiom expressing the idea that one shouldn't blindly accept what others say without looking into it first.

Comment: help me with this question too please. please Richard please. I need your help. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/542167/starting-ending-for-the-essay
Though it not the platform to make such question but I'm forced because it is very urgent and important to solve this. please help me